# Magento 2 Grunt Install Error on Ubuntu LEMP

Tags: magento2, php, nginx, grunt, ubuntu

> npm install -g grunt-cli

Showing Error on Grunt Install Error on Ubuntu LEMP:

```
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.5.5 -> 9.6.7
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.6.7
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.6.7 to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/matin/.npm/_logs/2023-05-30T06_36_18_355Z-debug-0.log
```

Ref: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/debug/

Comment: solved aftre using sudo npm install -g grunt-cli